# Method undefined for my type in a deque implementation in java

Tags: java, linked-list, queue, deque, arraydeque

So I am required to create a deque, or a double-ended queue in Java. But when I use some of the methods that were defined in the implementation of the deque, in my demonstration or driver program, I get an error saying the given method is undefined for the type that is my deque implementation class. So my toString() and size() methods don't show any error, but everything else like the enqueues and dequeues have an error. I realize this is must be a silly error but please help me understand. Thanks.

Here is my driver program that uses my deque class, followed by my implementation of the deque:

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;

public class DequeDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create an object for the Deque class
        ArrayDeque<Integer> cad = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();

        /*Adding integers to the deque at rear*/
        cad.enqueueRear(40);
        cad.dequeueRear(22);
        cad.enqueueFront(-4);
        cad.dequeueFront(16);

        System.out.println(cad.first());
        System.out.println(cad.last());
    }

}
```

Implementation of the deque:

```
public class ArrayDeque<T> implements DequeADT<T> {

    private final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
    private int front, rear, count;
    private T[] deque;

    //creates an empty deque using default capacity
    public ArrayDeque() {
        front = rear = count = 0;
        deque = (T[]) (new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY]);
    }

    //creates an empty deque using specified capacity
    public ArrayDeque (int initialCapacity) {
        front = rear = count = 0;
        deque = (T[])(new Object[initialCapacity]);
    }



    //adds an element to the rear of the deque
    public void enqueueRear(T element) {
        if(size() == deque.length) {
            System.out.println("The deque is full.");
            return;
        }

        deque[rear] = element;
        rear = (rear + 1)%deque.length;

        count++;

    }

    //adds an element to the front of the deque 
    public void enqueueFront(T element) {
        if(size() == deque.length) {
            System.out.println("The deque is full.");
            return;
        }

        if  (front == 0)
            front = deque.length - 1;
        else 
            front = (front -1)% deque.length;

        deque[front] = element;

        count++;

    }

    /*removes an element at the front of the deque and returns
     * a reference to it*/
    public T dequeueFront() throws EmptyCollectionException 
    {
            if (isEmpty())
                throw new EmptyCollectionException("deque");

            T result = deque[front];
            deque[front] = null;
            front = (front + 1)%deque.length;

            count--;
            return result;
    }



    /*removes an element at the rear of the deque and returns
     * a reference to it*/
    public T dequeueRear() throws EmptyCollectionException  {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("deque");

        T result = deque[rear -1];
        deque[rear -1] = null;
        rear = (rear -1)% deque.length;
        count--;
        return result;
    }

    //returns an element at the front of the deque
    public T first() {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("queue");
        T result = deque[front];
        return result;
    }

    //returns the element the deque rear
    public T last() {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("queue");
        T result = deque[rear -1];
        return result;
    }

    //returns true if deque is empty
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (count==0);
    }

    //returns the number of elements in the deque
    public int size() {
        return count;
    }

    //returns a string representation of the deque
    public String toString() {
        String queueElements = "";

        for(int i=front, j=0;j<count;i=(i+1)%deque.length, j++) {
            queueElements = queueElements + deque[i].toString() + " ";
        }
        return queueElements;
    }

}
```

Comment: Remove `import java.util.ArrayDeque;` - you aren't testing your class `ArrayDeque`, you're invoking the one from `java.util`

Comment: on top of what @ElliottFrisch has mentioned, within your main method, when you invoke `dequeueRear` you're attempting to pass an argument to it whereas the signature of the method is -->  `dequeueRear()`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That worked! Thank you SO much :)

Comment: @Aominè You're right, can't believe I didn't notice that. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a method that exists but there is no parameter in the method declaration. That method is

```
public T dequeueRear()
```

and you try to do the following

```
cad.dequeueRear(22);
```

You must do the following instead

```
cad.dequeueRear();
```